# How do you make an image follow your finger in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do you make an image follow your finger in objetive-c?

Answer (score 14):

- Create your [**UIView**](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) and configure it (or any subclass thereof such as a [**UIImageView**](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html))
- Set the position of your Image to be where the user is touching:

There are **four** delegate methods for accepting touch events which are a part of any class that inherits from [**UIResponder**](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html) such as a [**UIView**](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html). Use the delegate method that is most appropriate to you. If you want it to follow your finger, this will be [**-touchesMoved**](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesMoved:withEvent:):

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)toucheswithEvent:(UIEvent*)event {        
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    myImageView.center = pt;
}
```

Other **delegate methods** available to you are:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

I wrote an example application that does exactly what you want. It's a demo of drawing Quartz 2D graphics, but it draws a red square and black circle where you drag your finger and should be simple enough to follow:

[alt text http://brockwoolf.com/shares/stackoverflow/3445494/screen.png](http://brockwoolf.com/shares/stackoverflow/3445494/screen.png)

[Download Xcode project](http://brockwoolf.com/shares/stackoverflow/3445494/Quartz2DDemo.zip) (32kb)

Comment: The link is down, can you update it please ? I have exactly the same problem !

Answer (score 2):

there is an exellent post here.

by [Divan Visagie](http://divcode.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/hidden-menu-part-2-following-finger.html)

here is the relevant code (taken from the link above):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Find the path for the menu resource and load it into the menu array
    NSString *menuPlistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Menu" ofType:@"plist"];

    menuArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:menuPlistPath];

    //add some gestures
//    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeLeft:)];
//    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    //[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

//    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeRight:)];
//    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    //[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

}



float difference;
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint contentTouchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:content];
    difference = contentTouchPoint.x;
}


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    CGPoint pointInView = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

    float xTarget = pointInView.x - difference;
    if(xTarget > menuTable.frame.size.width)
        xTarget = menuTable.frame.size.width;
    else if( xTarget < 0)
        xTarget = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25
                     animations:^{

                         [content setFrame:CGRectMake(xTarget, content.frame.origin.y, content.frame.size.width, content.frame.size.height)];
                     }
     ];
}


-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{


    CGPoint endPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    float xTarget = endPoint.x - difference;
    if(xTarget < (menuTable.frame.size.width/2))
        xTarget = 0;
    else
        xTarget = menuTable.frame.size.width;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25
                     animations:^{

                         [content setFrame:CGRectMake(xTarget, content.frame.origin.y, content.frame.size.width, content.frame.size.height)];
                     }
     ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Apple [Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+Code) library comes with a well-written example, named [Touches](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html). It also demonstrates the new [UIGestureRecognizers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/GestureSupport/GestureSupport.html) feature in iOS 4.0.