# Need pointers for iphone app where a graphical object follows your finger

Tags: iphone, ipad, graphics, drag

I'm looking to do an iphone/ipad app which isn't a game but requires a graphical object on the screen to follow your finger so it can be placed where 'dropped'. Effectively this is drag and drop. I'm not quite sure where to start with this so am looking for tutorials, books or general advice.

Can anyone suggest good starters?

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982277/uiview-drag-image-and-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445494/how-do-you-make-an-image-follow-your-finger-in-objective-c), I believe it covers the kind of thing you're after.

After having a look on Google I also found this [tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/20/iphone-programming-tutorial-using-uitouch-to-drag-an-image-around-the-screen/) which may be of some use to you. It looks as though it covers exactly the kind of thing you're after in the sense of dragging something around and dropping it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the delegate function called 'touchesMoved. Here's a great tutorial about this subject:

Good luck.

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/ipad-development/how-to-image-moved-using-touch-function-in-ipad/