# how to drag and drop Image into a second one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have two images, the first one is a foreground and the second one is the background.
I want to merge both of them into a single Image.I want to be able to drag and drop the `frontImage` into only the `background` is it possible ?

Comment: don't understand what you're asking. Can you post some pictures?

Comment: Do you want to learn how to drag one image onto the second or do you want to learn how to merge them?

Comment: Exactly,I want to learn how to drag one image into the second

Comment: o.O I really don't understand what you want to do :|

Answer (score 0):

This can be super easy.

For example - You have a parent UIView and two image views:

```
UIView *_baseView; //as big as the screen.

UIImageView *_backgroundImageView; //as a subview on _baseView

UIImageView *_frontImageView; //as a subview on _baseView
```

Then You implement some kind of UIImageView movement by finger (for example [How do you make an image follow your finger in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445494/how-do-you-make-an-image-follow-your-finger-in-objective-c)  or search for something similar to know how to move UIView objects around if You don't know yet how).

And - once You release Your finger - You can take a screenshot from _baseView and get the image, where two subview ImageViews are combined in a way.

([How Do I Take a Screen Shot of a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview) or search something similar).

If You don't like, that You have to take screenshot of _baseView,  You could also add frontImageView as a subview to background image view and get the screenshot from backgroundImageView.

Hope this idea helps.