# Is it possible to create a pull to refresh without a table view?

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to know if it would be able to create a pull to refresh feature in ios using swift. I know how to do it when refreshing a table view but is it possible to do it without a table view just in a regular view controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can easily do it using `UIScrollView` as `UITableView` is subclass of `UIScrollView`

Comment: how would i set up the scroll view in this case

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905382/can-i-use-a-uirefreshcontrol-in-a-uiscrollview

Comment: don't forget to enable bounce on your scrollview as I forgot. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. As Nilesh Patel pointed it, it can be done using a scrollview; but also any kind of UIView would do it.

To do it on other views than UIScrollview, make your view draggable
move uiview with finger

Simply allow your view to be dragged, and detect the appropriate condition:

[How do you make an image follow your finger in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445494/how-do-you-make-an-image-follow-your-finger-in-objective-c)